# How to get a correlation matrix from a pairwise correlation data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, igraph, correlation

I have a pairwise correlation dataframe which looks like this (this is just the head) :

```
      var1                var2  corr
1  OTU3978 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.846
2  OTU4011 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855
3  OTU4929 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.829
4  OTU4317 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.850
5  OTU4816 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.807
6  OTU3902 UniRef90_A0A011QPQ2 0.836
7  OTU3339 UniRef90_A0A011RKI6 0.835
8  OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.801
9  OTU2085 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.843
10 OTU3542 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.866
```

I would like to get the correlation matrix from this dataframe 
I tried :

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph.data.frame(df,directed=FALSE)
A <-as_adjacency_matrix(G,names=TRUE,sparse=FALSE,attr="corr",type='lower')
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, it does not return me the correlation matrix. According to the data.frame I showed in my post, I should get lots of NAs (because not all the variables are correlated to each other) .

Comment: But isn't the idea that you're trying to get a correlation matrix from just the $corr vector?

Comment: True! But actually, I don't know if I should get a 10 rows (var1) x 10 columns (var2) matrix? Or a 15 x 15 matrix (because there are 15 different variables in my data.frame) ? In both case, I will get lots of NA that I will convert into 0 ?

Comment: So you have more vars than these 2? And is there correlation data between those as well?

Comment: Actually, `nrow(df)=1105854` . But it is not necessarly that all variables are not correlated to each other (for example, `OTU3978` might be only correlated to `UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8` , but `UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8` might be correlated to this OTU or to many others OTU , and vice versa) . And `var1` only correspond to OTUXXX and `var2` to UniRef90_XXX

Comment: I tried that : `matrix=acast(test, var1~var2, value.var="corr")` from the `library(reshape2)` , which gives me back a matrix. I just would like to know if my draft is suitable to make clusters? I mean, I would like to apply clustering on this matrix in order to build clusters.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Apologies for all the questions :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One approach is the `acast` you mentioned, but you can also use `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)

var1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
var2 <- c("E", "E", "F", "F")
corr <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, corr)
df
  var1 var2 corr
1    A    E  0.2
2    B    E  0.3
3    C    F  0.4
4    D    F  0.5
df <- spread(df, var2, corr)
df
  var1   E   F
1    A 0.2  NA
2    B 0.3  NA
3    C  NA 0.4
4    D  NA 0.5
```

Comment: It also works with the `tidyr` library, thanks. Do you know if it possible to put all the variables as rows and columns? I mean, not only put the OTUXXX variables in rows and the Uniref90_XXX in columns (or the contrary, anyway) , but put both variables (all the OTUXXX and Uniref90_XXX) in rows and also in columns?

Comment: But since there's no corr data for OTUXXX vs OTUXXX, those would all show as NA? Is that what you're after? I would probably just add all the values in the original var1 and var2 columns then.

Comment: Anyway, I will change the NA by 0 . It is just to try something later.